# Json arrays save in sql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to save Json arrays into sql database.  This is example. What is wrong in this code.

```
               {
                "product": [
               {
                 "money": "60",
                 "sum": "120"
                },
                {
                  "money": "50",
                  "sum": "100"
                }
              ]
             }

$json = json_decode($_POST['x'], TRUE);
$counter  = count($json['product']); 

for($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++){
$query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO table2 (money,sum) VALUES ('".$json['product'][$i]['money']."', '" .$json['product'][$i]['sum']."')");
      }
```

Comment: what error message do you have?

Comment: I don't have any message...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `foreach` loop it would be easier to write. It should give you something like this :

```
if (empty($json) || empty($json['product'])) {
    throw new Exception('Check JSON array.');
}

foreach ( $json['product'] as $product) {
    $query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO table2 (money,sum) VALUES ('".$product['money']."', '" .$product['sum']."')");
}
```

Writing it this way makes it easier to understand.

Comment: I am now test with empty but I don't have empty arrays :D

Comment: Are you using the console for debugging ? (F12 on Firefox for instance)
How do you know that this code is not working do you have logs somewhere in you PHP application ?

Comment: I think that this code not work because this query not to save in database :D

Comment: Maybe the query doesn't work because you insert you product money and sum as VARCHARS with sourrounding single quotes. Can you tell us what is the type for money and sum in table2 please ?

If it is a numeric type, you can try like this :
`$query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO table2 (money,sum) VALUES (".$product['money'].", " .$product['sum'].")");`